# Add dependency in gradle

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I have got any idea why my dependency not working.
This is my configuration:

```
ext {
   junitVersion = "4.11"

   libs = [
           junit : dependencies.create("junit:junit:4.11")
   ]
}

configure(subprojects) { subproject ->
    dependencies {
        testCompile(libs.junit)
    }
}
```

i have got error :

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'unit590'.
> Could not find method testCompile() for arguments [DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='junit', name='junit', version='4.11', configuration='default'}] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@785c1069.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `testCompile` configuration is declared by the `java` plugin. So before you can add dependencies to `testCompile`, you'll have to `apply plugin: "java"` to `subprojects`.

PS: The declaration of `libs` can be simplified as shown in Matt's answer. `configure(subprojects) { ... }` can be simplified to `subprojects { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am newbie gradle user :)

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
ext {
   junitVersion = "4.11"

   libs = [
           junit : "junit:junit:${junitVersion}"
   ]
}

configure(subprojects) { subproject ->
    dependencies {
        testCompile libs.junit
    }
}
```

the `dependencies` DSL relies on Groovy's [methodMissing](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+methodMissing+and+propertyMissing) impl and this, in the version of gradle I have to hand, looks like this

```
public Object methodMissing(String name, Object args) {
    Configuration configuration = configurationContainer.findByName(name)
    if (configuration == null) {
        if (!getMetaClass().respondsTo(this, name, args.size())) {
            throw new MissingMethodException(name, this.getClass(), args);
        }
    }

    Object[] normalizedArgs = GUtil.collectionize(args)
    if (normalizedArgs.length == 2 && normalizedArgs[1] instanceof Closure) {
        return doAdd(configuration, normalizedArgs[0], (Closure) normalizedArgs[1])
    } else if (normalizedArgs.length == 1) {
        return doAdd(configuration, normalizedArgs[0], (Closure) null)
    }
    normalizedArgs.each {notation ->
        doAdd(configuration, notation, null)
    }
    return null;
}
```

This will be called for each statement inside `dependencies{}` and provides a nice, simple DSL in place of calls to add/create etc.

My version will pass testCompile as the 1st string arg and the GAV notation string as the 2nd arg & hence it will go into the `doAdd` method as usual (with the string notation being resolved by the relevant `NotationParser` (in this case `org.gradle.api.internal.notations.DependencyStringNotationParser`).

Your current use instead makes it think you are seeking to call a method called [`DependencyHandler#testCompile`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html)